# Android Studio - Find most dominant color in wallpaper

Tags: java, android, launcher, wallpaper

I am working on developing an Android Launcher UI. Currently the launcher is working and has a few themes with different colors that can be changed in a settings menu.

Is there a way in Java to automatically find the most dominant color in the wallpaper image that is currently applied to the mobile device?

I think this would be a cool concept.

Any info is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Would the Palette class in the Support Library suit your needs?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/graphics/Palette.html

Comment: This is interesting and useful, but there isn't anything to actually get the most dominant color. You can only retrieve, vibrant or muted colors.

Comment: Ah, so there isn't a way to somehow get RGB or hexadecimal color from the most dominant color of the device's wallpaper?

Answer (score 0):

You could use Palette from Android support library
If you want to get the dominant color, just use palette.getDominantColor()
It will give you the integer value of the dominant color in ARGB.